# Import data to Excel by VBA and get the same style as do manually

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to connect excel to mysql manually, which is to click Data tab->From other sources->Data connection wizard...

The data loaded appear in this style. Note that by default the head line has a different background color than the lines below, and the background color of the other lines changes, the border color is white, etc.

[image]

I also learned how to import data by vba.

```
Sub ConnetMySQL()

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
    "Server = localhost; " & _
    "Poer = 3306" & _
    "Database = NBA;" & _
    "UID = root; PASSWORD = ; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open


    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `nba`.`game`"
    rs.Open strSQL, conn


    Dim myArray()

    myArray = rs.GetRows()

    kolumner = UBound(myArray, 1)
    rader = UBound(myArray, 2)

    For K = 0 To kolumner ' Using For loop data are displayed
        Worksheets("Game").Range("a5").Offset(0, K).Value = rs.Fields(K).Name
        For R = 0 To rader
           Worksheets("Game").Range("A5").Offset(R + 1, K).Value = myArray(K, R)
        Next
    Next


    rs.Close
    'MsgBox strOutput
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

But the data loaded by vba doesn't have any style.
[image]

I believe I must miss something in my code. How should I modify the code so that the data loaded by vba have the same style as the data loaded manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will look for 1 table on the active sheet (assuming the ONLY information is the table). It does not matter about the size of the table. It will assume that there are headers. It will then format as your picture is formatted.

```
Sub test()

Set X = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, X, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    X.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"


End Sub
```

The below code is untested, but it should work for you:

```
Sub ConnetMySQL()

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
"Server = localhost; " & _
"Poer = 3306" & _
"Database = NBA;" & _
"UID = root; PASSWORD = ; OPTION=3"
conn.Open


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `nba`.`game`"
rs.Open strSQL, conn


Dim myArray()

myArray = rs.GetRows()

kolumner = UBound(myArray, 1)
rader = UBound(myArray, 2)

For K = 0 To kolumner ' Using For loop data are displayed
    Worksheets("Game").Range("a5").Offset(0, K).Value = rs.Fields(K).Name
    For R = 0 To rader
       Worksheets("Game").Range("A5").Offset(R + 1, K).Value = myArray(K, R)
    Next
Next

Set X = Sheets("Game").UsedRange
Sheets("Game").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, X, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
 X.Select
    Sheets("Game").ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"

rs.Close
'MsgBox strOutput
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

end sub
```